# Regex matching any or no character except for given exceptions

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match a string that is not preceded by a character, but possibly nothing at all.

Example: I want to match all cases of "test" in a bracket, except when they are preceded by "[" or "|".

Example strings:

```
(1) {this is a test}              // match
(2) {this [is] also a test }      // match
(3) {test}                        // match
(4) {this is the third |test}     // no match
(5) {this is the third [test}     // no match
```

My first attempt was this:

```
\{.*[^\||\[]test.*\}
```

But of course, this doesn't match (3), because there is no character between the bracket and "test".

Then I tried a negative lookaround:

```
\{.*(?!\||\[)test.*\}
```

but this matches all of the example strings. And apparently, a lookbehind isn't supported in javascript or the environment I'm using.

Is there a way to do this? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `test` in a *character class*, matches any combination of `t`, `e`, `s` and `t` letters.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I'm not experienced with regex at all, but I don't see a character class containing 
    "test" 
in the given search patterns.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my mistake :) But my note is still valid ;)

Comment: @JulianHzg did you want to match only the string `test` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I want to match the whole thing. (And store the parts before and after "test" in variables, but that shouldn't be a problem I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language won't accept lookbehinds then you may consider the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
^(?=\{)[^}]*?[^\[|]test[^}]*}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mL6eB8/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
\{[^\{\}]*(?<![\[|])test[^\{\}]*\}
```

Steps:

- \{, Start with left brace.
- [^\{\}]*, Followed by zero or more non braces.
- (?<![\[|])test, Followed by test that isn't immediately after `|` or `[`.
- [^\{\}]*, Followed by zero or more non braces.
- \}, Followed by a right brace.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be the right solution if lookbehinds would function. Given the unfortunate limitations, the workaround offered by Avinash Raj is exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem as long as next time you mention the programming language :)